# I'm using R language but when I run the program this error appears:

Tags: r

```
dataset_colnames <- names(rf.tune$trainingData)[-ncol(rf.tune$trainingData)]
testing <- test_data[,dataset_colnames]
Error in [.data.frame(test_data, , dataset_colnames) :
undefined columns selected
testing <- testing[complete.cases(testing),]
Error: object 'testing' not found
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: The first line is generating an incorrect value.  You are you trying to do?  Please provide a sample of your data.

Comment: thanks for your reply，I found the mistake.